# Django/Wagtail ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields'

Tags: django, wagtail

I am using Django and Wagtail to create a site, which had been working well for some time. However, after some problems with anaconda, reinstalling etc, I now get this problem when I run python manage.py runserver:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (C:\Users\Tomo_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py)
```

I am not entirely sure what to do, as nothing has changed in my settings, and there isn't even a fields file, but rather a fields folder. It's like it's looking for an object in a folder.

Entire trace:

```
(base)>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "G:\OneDrive\Academia\Computer-Science\Portfolio\Wagtail\portfolio\portfolio\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.urls import pages as wagtailadmin_pages_urls
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\pages.py", line 4, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.views.pages import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\pages\history.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.filters import PageHistoryReportFilterSet
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\filters.py", line 1, in <module>
    import django_filters
  File "C:\Users\Tomo_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django_filters\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>     
    from .filters import *
  File "C:\Users\Tomo_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django_filters\filters.py", line 12, in <module>     
    from .conf import settings
  File "C:\Users\Tomo_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django_filters\conf.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .utils import deprecate
  File "C:\Users\Tomo_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django_filters\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py)
```

Not much info has come from googling, so any help would be much appreciated.

Wagtail version = 2.11.3

Django version = 3.1.4

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is your version of django-filters? Error comes from there

Comment: Can you list your requirements.txt file? It looks like an error with the version of django-filters that you're using. It may not be compatible with another package.

Comment: Django-filter is either 2.0.2 or 2.2.0. Looking at my Python38/site-packages folder, it seems I have two copies of a number of packages. I have added a picture to show the packages in my folder.

Answer (score 3):

For those who come here in future and needs a more precise solution than just `--upgrade`, exactly `django-filters 2.3` fixes that bug.

https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1261#issuecomment-680289892

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting all django and wagtail modules in my python38/site-packages folders and reinstalling them with `pip install [packagenames] --upgrade` command.